# Passing data from one controller action to another - Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom module with a controller action which performs a certain function,

```
class Company_CustomModule_ActionController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function doAction()
    {
        // do something

    }
}
```

I have another controller in the same module (lets say "test"). I would like to call an action within this "test" controller in the above mentioned controller and pass it a parameter like,

```
 class Company_CustomModule_ActionController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {
        public function doAction()
        {
          // do something

         // call the index in the "Test" controller
         Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse($data)
                        ->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('company/test'))
                        ->sendResponse();

         }
       }
```

My goal is to pass some data from the Action controller to the Test Controller and execute the index action in the Test Controller from within the Action Controller.

Note: in essence, I would like to pass on the POST data received by the Action Controller to the Test Controller.

How would I go about doing this? any guidance would he helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not overly familiar with Magento, but since it's built on the Zend Framework you should be able to use the forward helper and pass your data in the `params` parameter:

`return $this->_forward('test', 'company', $module, $params);`